# How do I properly set position on a scaled sprite?

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, sprite

My assets are 70x70 pixels, and that is way to big, so I called `sprite.setScale(0.5f);` to make them smaller. Only problem is the location isn't changed when you set the scale, so it is drawing as if it was a 70x70 image.

Screenshot:
[Screenshot http://puu.sh/aIDEm/975e4b32ed.jpg/ss%20(2014-08-07%20at%2012.41.47).jpg](http://puu.sh/aIDEm/975e4b32ed.jpg/ss%20(2014-08-07%20at%2012.41.47).jpg)

Here's my drawing code:

```
public void draw(String spriteName, Location location) {
    Sprite sprite = atlas.createSprite(spriteName);
    sprite.setScale(0.5f);
    sprite.setPosition(location.x, location.y);
    sprite.draw(batch);
}
```

**EDIT:** This is how it's supposed to look.
[Screenshot http://puu.sh/aIE9b/aed7b4ac14.png](http://puu.sh/aIE9b/aed7b4ac14.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are trying to zoom into your actual game environment. You can achieve this without setting the scale to every object in your game. If you implement a camera (since you are using libgdx) you can simply zoom into your game at 2x and it will give you a scaled view of you game.

Follow this tutorial and experiment!
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera

Answer (score 0):

You can always get a satisfying width using getWidth() * scale;